# Bullet pointer becoming zero

Tags: c++, bullet-physics, memory

I am currently trying to implement the Bullet physics into my game project. However, when i add some rigid bodies to the scene, i occasionally get an error in *btDbvtBroadphase.cpp* at the line
  *if(proxy->stage==STAGECOUNT)* (line 294).

If i then inspect the **proxy** pointer, it points to *0x0*. If I go back to the function *btCollisionWorld::updateSingleAabb(btCollisionObject * colObj)* on the call stack, and inspect the member **m_broadphaseHandle**, it is non-zero, which is being passed as first parameter to *btDbvtBroadphase::setAabb(btBroadphaseProxy* absproxy, const btVector3& aabbMin, const btVector3& aabbMax, btDispatcher** __ *formal)*.
In this method it is being cast into a *btDbvtProxy* pointer and stored in **proxy**. What I don't get here is, why **proxy** becomes *0x0*, even though a valid pointer is being passed to the function.

The call stack looks like this:

```
MyProject.exe!btDbvtBroadphase::setAabb(btBroadphaseProxy * absproxy, const btVector3 & aabbMin, const btVector3 & aabbMax, btDispatcher * __formal) Line 294   C++
MyProject.exe!btCollisionWorld::updateSingleAabb(btCollisionObject * colObj) Line 171   C++
MyProject.exe!btCollisionWorld::updateAabbs() Line 204  C++
MyProject.exe!btCollisionWorld::performDiscreteCollisionDetection() Line 220    C++
MyProject.exe!btDiscreteDynamicsWorld::internalSingleStepSimulation(float timeStep) Line 492    C++
MyProject.exe!btDiscreteDynamicsWorld::stepSimulation(float timeStep, int maxSubSteps, float fixedTimeStep) Line 452    C++
```

The initialization of bullet looks like this:

```
broadphase = new btDbvtBroadphase();
collisionConfiguration = new btDefaultCollisionConfiguration();
dispatcher = new btCollisionDispatcher(collisionConfiguration);
solver = new btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver;

world = new btDiscreteDynamicsWorld(dispatcher, broadphase, solver, collisionConfiguration);
world->setGravity(btVector3(0.0f, -10.0f, 0.0f));
```

I create RigidBodies procedurally and this is, how I add them:

```
bp.mesh = new btTriangleMesh(true, false);

for (int i = 0; i < bp.numFaces; ++i)
{
    btVector3 a(vertices[indices[i * 3 + 0]].position.x, vertices[indices[i * 3 + 0]].position.y, vertices[indices[i * 3 + 0]].position.z);
    btVector3 b(vertices[indices[i * 3 + 1]].position.x, vertices[indices[i * 3 + 1]].position.y, vertices[indices[i * 3 + 1]].position.z);
    btVector3 c(vertices[indices[i * 3 + 2]].position.x, vertices[indices[i * 3 + 2]].position.y, vertices[indices[i * 3 + 2]].position.z);
    bp.mesh->addTriangle(a, b, c);
}

btMotionState* ms = new btDefaultMotionState;
btBvhTriangleMeshShape* shape = new btBvhTriangleMeshShape(bp.mesh, true);

sect->rigidBody = new btRigidBody(0.0f, ms, shape);

btWorld->addRigidBody(sect->rigidBody, 64, 128);
```

My question now is, why **proxy** occasionally points to *0x0*, even though it should be a valid pointer? I downloaded and successfully compiled bullet-2.82-r2704 with VS2012 and changed the project settings from /MT(d) to /MD(d), if this does matter.

---

Edit: I may also mention that the rigid bodies are added in a different thread, than the thread in which I initialize and simulate the bullet physics. Can this cause any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was in fact, caused by adding rigid bodies from different threads. After I moved the call to *btDynamicsWorld::addRigidBody* into the main thread, I did not receive this error again.